# unexpected behavior of while loop variable with scanf reading string

Tags: c

Value of n changes abruptly in this below code when i am including scanf to read string. i also tried %*c but its still showing the same error.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>

 int main()
 {
  char str[3];
   int n;
   int t,p=0;
   scanf("%d",&t);

   while(t--)
    {
      printf("t=%d ",t);
      scanf("%d",&n);
       while(n!=0)
        {
          printf("n=%d",n);
          p=0;   
          scanf("%s",str);
          getchar();
          if(strcmp(str,"lhx")==0)
          printf("lhx");
          else
          printf("hhb");
          n--;
         }
      }
     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `char str[3];` --> `char str[4];` or more

Comment: Conclusion: Have a red light turned on for every use of `[]` (and every use of a variable declared with `[]`). This is probably the most common cause in C programs performing a wrong memory access operation (leading to either a memory access violation or a an unexpected result (and in general - **undefined behavior** of the program)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by `if(strcmp(str,"lhx")==0)`, you are inputting 3 characters. But `str` has memory for only `3` characters. To scanf it as a *string*, you'll need at least 4 bytes of memory for `str`.

You could fix by changing it to:

```
  char str[4];
```

But then again, you'll have the same problem when you input 4 characcters. Use `fgets` instead of `scanf().` `fgets()` will protect against buffer overflow.

Aside: use a standard signature for `main()`:  `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char**argv)` or its equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your array can hold just 3 characters

```
char str[3];
```

So 2 valid characters followed by a null terminator but you check it against a string with 3 characters.

So change your array to

```
char str[4];
```

scanning a string using scanf() is always a bad idea use `fgets()` instead.